# How to stream data in Jasper reports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working on Jasper Reports using JasperSoft Studio. I have a huge data set (around 50 million) that needed to be filled in the reports. I can able to get them with pagination.

But unfortunately while I try to export data in Excel/PDF formats where pagination cannot be applied as per the requirement, it is taking too long to load **ANY** data and the user has to wait until the report generation is over.

Is there any way to generate and send the data to the client and keep them adding there after? So that the user will know something is loading instead of make them to wait for long time.

I tried the settings given here, http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534989/settings-required-generating-large-reports. But still It is loading the file altogether only and not in an expected way.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Is there any way to generate and send the data to the client and keep them adding there after? So that the user will know something is loading instead of make them to wait for long time.` - Are you asking about some kind of progress bar?

Comment: @AlexK No, not the progress bar. Something like starting the download of the file immediately after reading some data in MySQL instead of reading the entire data and then send the output to the browser.

Comment: `Something like starting the download of the file` - What file, with the part of data from DB? Pdf for example?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I mean starting the process of downloading the file when some data is available instead of  reading all the data in the DB and make it as a complete PDF/Excel file and sending it to the client..